# Machine Precision or Machine Epsilon Formula

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm reading Heath's Scientific Computing.

The machine epsilon is denoted by $\epsilon$.
With rounding to nearest, the machine epsilon can be determined by the following formula:

$\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} \beta^{1-p}$

where $\beta$ is the base and $p$ is the precision (i.e. number of significant digits).

For $\beta = 10$ and $p = 3$ since $1 + 0.005 = 1.01 > 1$, $\epsilon = 0.005 =  \frac{1}{2} 10^{1-3}= \frac{1}{2} \beta^{1-p}$

For $\beta = 2$ and $p = 3$ since $(1 + 0.001)_2 = (1.01)_2 > 1$, $\epsilon = (0.001)_2 = \frac{1}{2} 2^{1-3} = \frac{1}{2} \beta^{1-p}$

For $\beta = 3$ and $p = 3$ since $(1 + 0.002)_3 = (1.01)_3 > 1$, $\epsilon = (0.002)_3 = \frac{2}{27}$ which does not agree with $\frac{1}{2}3^{1-3}= \frac{1}{18}$

Is the formula only applicable to bases that can represent $\frac{1}{2}$ exactly or did I misunderstand how the formula is to be applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine epsilon $\epsilon$ is the distance between 1 and the next floating point number.

Machine precision $u$ is the accuracy of the basic arithmetic operations. This number is also know as the unit roundoff.

When the precision is $p$ and the radix is $\beta$ we have
$$ \epsilon = \beta^{1-p}.$$
To see this, simply a 1 to the last digit. If we round to nearest, then
$$ u = \frac{1}{2} \beta^{1-p}.$$

The wrong formula gave you the right result for $\beta \in \{2,10\}$ because you rounded up, i.e. applied the default rounding mode for human calculators.

To be fair, the literature is not in agreement and different terms abound. I recommend that you follow Higham's book: "Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms".

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing real numbers with their representations.

You write $(1 + 0.002)_3 \stackrel?= (1.01)_3,$
which is an abuse of notation to begin with;
the left side is not *equal* to the right, it *rounds* to the right-hand side
when $p = 3.$

The question Heath appears to be trying to answer is,
"What is the largest relative error due to a single rounding off?"
For $\beta = 10$ and $p = 3$ we can use $1.005$ as a test case because that is the very smallest number between $1.00$ and $1.01$ that rounds up instead of down.

But when $\beta = 3$ and $p = 3,$
lots of other numbers that are less than $1.002_3$ also round off to $1.01_3$, for example $(1 + 0.001112)_3.$

In fact, the very smallest number between $1$ and $1.01_3$ that rounds up to $1.01_3$
is
$$1.001111\ldots_3 = 1 + \frac1{18}.$$